# To find Image of curve in Complex Domain

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry

Find the Image of the Curve $$Arg\left(\frac{z-3}{z-i}\right)=\frac{\pi}{6}$$ in the $X$ axis. Its a Multiple choice question and the Options to this question are again in the form of $$Arg\left(\frac{z-a}{z-b}\right)=\theta$$

we normally can do it by taking $z=x+iy$ and Using $Arg(\frac{z_1}{z_2})=Arg(z_1)-Arg(z_2)$ we get the curve as a Circle with say some center as $(h,k)$. Then we can find the Image of the circle as image of its center about the given line and Finally we can convert it again to Complex form.

But i want to know how can we do it only in complex domain that is without using cartesian variables $x$ and $y$

Comment: Do you mean you want to find the equation, in a similar form, of the reflection of this curve in the real axis?

Comment: Yes of course how can we do it directly using complex variable $z$. what i know is if $z \in \mathbb{C}$, its Reflection in Real axis is $z^*$. so if $f(z)$ is a curve, then its Reflection in real axis is $f(z^*)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First draw the original locus, which is a part circle on the chord connecting the points $z=3$ and $z=i$ and extending into the first quadrant, so that every point on the arc subtends the angle $\frac{\pi}{6}$ with the chord.
The reflection in the real axis will be an arc in the fourth quadrant based on the chord connecting $z=3$ and $z=-i$, so, when expressed in similar form, the locus will be $$\arg\left(\frac{z+i}{z-3}\right)=\frac{\pi}{6}$$